# nlfilter taking same values twice

Tags: matlab

I used `nlfilter` for a test function of mine as follows:

```
function funct
clear all;
clc;
I = rand(11,11);
ld = input('Enter the lag = ') % prompt for lag distance
A = nlfilter(I, [7 7], @dirvar);

% Subfunction
    function [h] = dirvar(I)
        c = (size(I)+1)/2
        EW = I(c(1),c(2):end)
        h = length(EW) - ld
    end
end
```

The function works fine but it is expected that `nlfilter` progresses element by element, but in first two iterations the values of EW will be same `0.2089 0.4162 0.9398 0.1058`. But then onwards for all iterations the next element is selected, for 3rd it is `0.4162 0.9398 0.1058 0.1920`, for 4th it is `0.9398 0.1058 0.1920 0.5201` and so on. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to worry about. It happens because *nlfilter* needs to evaluate your function to know what kind of output to create. So it uses *feval* once before starting to move across the image. The output from this *feval* call is what you see the first time.

From the *nlfilter* code:

```
% Find out what output type to make.
rows = 0:(nhood(1)-1);
cols = 0:(nhood(2)-1);
b = mkconstarray(class(feval(fun,aa(1+rows,1+cols),params{:})), 0, size(a));

% Apply fun to each neighborhood of a
f = waitbar(0,'Applying neighborhood operation...');
for i=1:ma,
    for j=1:na,
        x = aa(i+rows,j+cols);
        b(i,j) = feval(fun,x,params{:});
    end
    waitbar(i/ma)
end
```

The 4th line call to *eval* is what you observe as the first output from EW, but it is not used to anything other than making the b matrix the right class. All the proper iterations happen in the *for* loop below. This means that the "duplicate" values you observe does not affect your final output matrix, and you need not worry.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know what the `length` function does? It does not give you the Euclidean length of a vector, but rather the largest dimension of a vector (so in your case, that should be 4). If you want the Euclidean length (or 2-norm), use the function `norm` instead. If your code does the right thing, you might want to use something like:

```
sz = size(I,2);
h = sz - (sz+1)/2 - ld;
```

In your example, this means that depending on the lag you provide, the output should be constant. Also note that you might want to put semicolons after each line in your subfunction and that using `clear all` as the first line of a function is useless since a function will always be executed in its own workspace (that will however clear persistent or global variables, but you don't use them in your code).

Comment: I use the `length` function to obtain the number of elements. I didn't use semicolons here as I wanted to check how the function progresses. Thanks for your suggestions!